# Demonstrate $S / R$ is equivalence relation in $A / R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on a set A and $R \subseteq S$,

prove $S / R$ is an equivalence relation on $A / R$.

Comment: @BLAZE Your edit is wrong. Please restaure the original post.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Are you sure? What is wrong please?

Comment: @BLAZE It should not be $\setminus$ but $/$.

Comment: if set A the the set of equivalence classes modulo R  that A/R

Comment: I didn't see the question earlier, but yes, '/' makes sense and is true but '\' is just wrong (it's set difference).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Okay, my apologies, getting tired and wasn't thinking straight, sorry

Comment: @J.-E. Pin Fixed that. It would be nice if the question defined $S/R$ but there's only one thing it can mean.

Answer (score 1):

$S/R$ is an equivalence relation on $A/R$ induced by S. 
$S/R$ can be defined as follows, for $x, y \in A/R$:
$$
x (S/R) y \iff (\forall a \in x)(\forall b \in y) a S b \tag{*}
$$

Because $R$ is compatible with $S$ ($R \subseteq S$) and R and S are equivalence relations, (*) is equivalent to:
$$
x (S/R) y \iff (\exists a \in x)(\exists b \in y) a S b \tag{**}
$$

Because all equivalence classes in $A/R$ are nonempty, (*) obviously implies (**), so only the other direction needs proving. So assume (**). For $x, y \in A/R$, there are $a_0 \in x, b_0 \in y$ such that $a_0 S b_0$. Then for any $a \in x, b \in y$ we have: $a R a_0$ and $b_0 R b$, hence $a S a_0$ and $b_0 S b$. By transitivity of $S$, $a S b$.

Using (*) and/or (**), it's easy to show that $S/R$ is an equivalence relation. By (**), Proving that $S/R$ is reflexive uses the fact that $R \subseteq S$. That $S/R$ is symmetric and transitive follows immediately from $S$ having those properties.